# Spring framework: bean config

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to learn spring framework and then springboot.

I have been watching videos..almost every video talks about different ways of configuring beans, but i am not able to understand which config option is being used by reatime projects…and if any of them got deprecated or were with older versions of spring framework

Any insights on this would reall help me understand this…thanks a lot

I am a java developer but never worked in spring.

Went through multiple tutorials and videos from different places.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my experience of working with spring. It may differ from the experience of other developers, so here I talk only about my personal opinion

It always depends.
Most of the recent projects in which I have been involved have always used the class level annotation approach. Beans were created with `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository` annotations, which we used to mark each class for creating a bean.

However, if you need to change behaviour of the specific beans provided by the spring you can always do it in the configuration. In this example I change the JpaTransactionManager bean by adding my own DataSource

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

  @Bean(name = "jpaTransactionManager")
  public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

I believe that the combination of these two approaches is classic for modern projects at this time.

There is also an approach where we create a bean using the `@Bean` annotation in a class labeled with the `@Configuration` annotation. I have also seen this in some projects with legacy code, as well as in projects that follow Domain Driven Design

I have never seen xml based bean configuration in real project. I suspect that it is outdated and can be found in very old projects